# Obtener el numero de filas con información que contiene una columna con macros

Tags: vba

Tengo el siguiente Excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito obtener la cantidad de filas que tengo en la columna B4 hasta donde se muestre infromación en este caso seria B10 pero, no siempre va hacer la misma cantidad de filas siempre estaria variando.

Comment: siempre parte en B4? siempre habrá algún dato? o habrá digamos en B10 nada pero en B11 continúa con datos hasta B20 por decir algo

Comment: Siempre partiria de B4, siempre habrá por lo menos 1 dato y nunca se saltara la infromación a otra fila, siempre sera seguida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código siguiente te lee hasta encontrar una celda en blanco, en el ejemplo parte desde B5 porque B4 es la cabecera de la columna por lo tanto no hay que tomarla en cuenta, además esta rutina te incluye en la cuenta la celda blanca que encontró por lo que hay que restarle 1 al final

```
Sub RowsCounter()
      Dim x As Integer
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      NumRows = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
      Range("B1").Select
      For x = 1 To NumRows
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Next
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      MsgBox x - 1
End Sub
```